# SYCL parallel_for condition as a while loop

Tags: c++, intel, intel-oneapi, sycl

I am new to the oneAPI with SYCL and I have the following function

```
q.submit([&](auto &h) {
     h.parallel_for(range<1>(size), [=](id<1> idx) {
               m_Add(C,A,B,idx);
               m_Multiply(D,C,A,idx); 
             });

   }).wait();
```

I understand that the parallel_for function acts like

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++)
```

I would like to run these `m_Add` and `m_Multiply` functions depending on a while loop condition like `D < A` so the parallel_for function runs `while(D < A)`

Is it possible to achieve this with any other function that the accelarator executes these functions within a while loop ?

Comment: If `D` changes throughout the loop, and the loop condition depends on it, then parallelism is not possible without manually coming up with some algorithm for it.  If some thread encounters a `! (D<A)` case somewhere in its temporary partial `D`, even stopping all the other threads doesn't give any obvious way to combine those results into a state that was as if a serial loop had stopped there.

Comment: So TL:DR: no, I don't expect an API to allow a data-dependent exit condition for a parallel_for, only cases where the loop trip-count can be computed before the first iteration.  But I haven't used OneAPI or SYCL.